# URL rewriting don't work in production with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use URL rewriting with htaccess, it works on local but failed on production. My host is 1and1.

My url is :
https://website.com/service.php?id=100&title=page-title

and I would like
https://website.com/service/100/page-title.html

I use this in my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^service/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /service.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Any idea about this error ?

Comment: It could be that your production Apache is different from your local.  Did you verify that the rewrite module is loaded?  How about production error logs?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, need to add `Options -MultiViews` in .htaccess
Thx